# Libpcap on Cygwin

Tags: cygwin

I recently installed Cygwin, and while trying to get Reaver onto it I got the following error: `pcap library not found!`. Although I think Cygwin is a terrifically useful tool, I'm still not used to not having a package manager, and am having trouble setting it up. [Another question on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396251/help-installing-libpcap-on-cygwin) seems to indicate that I need WinPcap. I downloaded the file and installed as described by camino's answer. However, `./configure` still returning the error. Is some modification of Reaver itself required? If not, what should I do? Thanks!

Comment: Note: I already have `libsqlite3-devel` installed, which is Reaver's other dependency.

Answer (score 2):

libpcap is not available on cygwin, for a obvious reason:

libpcap needs to work at system network interface level, while
cygwin is only in user space.
The old link you reported was in reality using a cygwin cross-compiler
to build a mingw program.